# What are the relative merits of writing SQL Server CLR UDTs as `struct` or `class`?

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr, user-defined-types

Just about every code sample for SQL Server CLR user-defined types implement the type as a `struct`. However, [Microsoft indicates that creating them as `class` is also an option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131082.aspx), but I can't seem to find any documentation or even discussion on the relative merits of each alternative.

In what situations would one choose to implement a SQL CLR UDT as a struct or class, respectively?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the recommendation is to have them as structures. But note:

> However, you can use inheritance when you structure your classes and you can call such methods in the managed code implementation of the type.

Now, since `struct`s can't inherit, if you plan to *use* inheritance, you're going to have to have it as a `class`.

Comment: But *why* is "the recommendation [to] have them as structures"? Why would one not always use the more versatile `class`?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - there's no publicly given reason, so far as I'm aware. But if you implement your type as a `struct`, you're a lot more likely to, for instance, implement a type for which native serialization will work.